# Pythonで対象ディレクトリの複数のjavaファイルを探索し、定義されているクラス名を取得したい

Tags: python

対象とするディレクトリ内の複数のjavaファイルを探索していき、定義されているクラス名を所得したいです。例えば、target_dir に Car.java と Train.java がある場合、「Car」と「Train」というクラス名を受け取りたいです。また、単純にファイル名をクラス名として返すのではなく、一つずつファイルを探索していく形を取りたいです。

作成してみたのですが、一つのjavaファイルしか読みこむことができず、解決策が思い浮かばない状況です。修正箇所及びより良い実装方法がございましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top='./target_dir'):
  for file in files:
    if not file.lower().endswith(('.java')):
       continue

    filePath = os.path.join(root, file)

    #一行ずつ読み込む
    with open(filePath) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    #改行は省く
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in lines]
    print(lines)
    
    #classの記述の後に続くコードを表示させる
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if "class" in lines[i]:
            classline = lines[i]
    print(classline)
    print(classline[classline.index("class")+1])
```

[image: エラー画面]

Comment: 発生しているエラーの名称`UnicodeDecodeError`で検索すれば色々と見つかると思うのですが。例えばこのサイトの中でもこんな記事など。[Python プログラム実行時にエラー: UnicodeDecodeError](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/74396/26370), [Windows　文字コードに関するエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91540/26370), [自作パッケージをpipでインストールするとエラーとなってしまいます。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91350/26370) ファイルのopen時に`encoding=`パラメータで相応しいエンコーディング種別を指定すれば、該当のエラーは解決出来るのでは？ やりたい事ができるかどうかは、それが解決してからでしょう。

Comment: コンパイルが通っているのかどうか、と、なぜJavaではなくPythonなのか？がよく分かりません。また抽出されるクラスはコメント内でもいいのか？など諸条件が不明です。
簡単でいいので、目的などを併記して頂けると回答しやすいと思いますよ。すでに解決済みのようですが。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

正規表現を使ってクラス名を列挙する例です。

**サンプルコード**

```
import glob
import re

dir_path = r"./target_dir" 
pattern = re.compile(r"\s?class\s+(\w+)")

for path in glob.glob(rf"{dir_path}/*.java"):
    with open(path, "r", encoding="sjis") as f:
        s = f.read()
        for m in re.finditer(pattern, s):
            class_name = m.group(1)
            print(f'{class_name} クラスが"{f.name}"で見つかりました。')
```

- ファイル内の複数のクラスを抽出できます。
- フォルダの再帰処理はしません。
- コメント行の判別をしません。
- ファイルのエンコーディングをシフトJISに決め打ちで処理します。

Comment: 重箱の隅(かつ、これは質問者が考えるべきこと)かと思いますが、 [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) や [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10) を取り逃しそうです。